# Is it a PI controller always a good solution for speed control in treadmills?

Tags: motor-controller

This topic got me confused again. I'm trying to regulate the speed of a treadmill, i.e, maintain the desired speed with load variations (the person on the tread). It's a PMDC motor. I have two scenarios:

**First scenario:**

A simple algorithm that samples speed of the motor, compares it with setpoint and increases/decreases duty cycle at a certain rate to avoid sudden changes in speed until the setpoint (desired speed) is reached. No computations for PI controller here.
[image]

**Second scenario** : **A PI Controller**

Record the speed step response of the motor, then find the best PI parameters for the task. But here's the point.

Let's put an example. Say that a setpoint of 340 RPM is given.

The first sceneario will then increase duty cycle slowly (due to duty cycle ramping) until 340 RPM is reached, since I'm continuously reading the speed.

For the second scenario to respond like the first one, I have to tune PI parameters for slow response. But I think that load compensation should be fast, right?

What's the right way to go?

Comment: Nobody is going to say it’s the right way to go because, without much doubt, it’ll need some or a lot of tweaking irrespective of how fine you might describe the theoretical operation.

Comment: Alright. I was actually looking for some suggestions about both of the approaches.

Comment: Well, your first scenario is flawed because you will never re read the demand input until the actual feedback signal exactly equals the old demand value. Maybe that’s what you want but it’s not really an EE question.

Comment: In addition to the flaw pointed out by @Andyaka, your first scenario has an integrated controller embedded in it -- incrementing or decrementing the PWM based on the sign of the error is the same as limiting the error magnitude to one and integrating.

Comment: What is hard about having a nice well-tuned PI loop that is driven by a setpoint that is incremented at a speed that makes the user happy?

Comment: Okay. I will try an embedded PI controller with manual tuning until getting the desired behavior.

Comment: I just had confusion if the PI can do the speed ramping and compensate for the load at the same time. I think that in another post you had suggested ramping the RPM setpoint.